# Can I upgrade my scimitar past superior?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok so I have the steel smithing perk in blacksmith. I've upgraded a scimitar to superior. It will not go any higher at the moment. Is there a skill I can get to upgrade it past superior or will it stay that way?

Comment: Just level up smithing, or get a blacksmith’s potion. You should be able to get it to legendary eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple cumulative sources of improvements for smithing:

- Skill
- Perks
- Potions (Fortify Smithing)
- Item Enchantment (Fortify Smithing)

They can all stack and improve your smithing quality.

The quality levels are:

- Fine
- Superior
- Exquisite
- Flawless
- Epic
- Legendary

You can find more details at the [UESP Wiki Page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smithing)

Answer (score 0):

With the relevant perk for the item you're trying to improve, you can hone it to Exquisite with a total skill level of only 40.  That's Base skill + Fortify Smithing Potions or Enchants.  If you're stashing away the best smithing gear your find in each armor slot, 40 is a trivial target.